# Throw a 404 error on unsuccessful authentication: devise + rails custom auth strategy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have a custom auth strategy (it is the default strategy), which has an authenticate! function.

```
def authenticate!
  if validation_success
    success!(resource)
  else
    fail(:invalid_token)
  end
end
```

I want to modify it so that in the 'else' part of the loop, I directly return a 404 from this code itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
```

The production environment automatically handles record not found and routing errors with a 404.